# Opening separate connections on Python server

Tags: python, sockets, http, server, request

I’m building a Python server, so far I have been able to retrieve HTML files.. and everything is working as it should. But my server has to open and retrieve the contents of HTML file and it will parse the HTML for embedded links such as images, css stylesheet and js. Then it has to make separate connections to the web server to retrieve the embedded files. i.e if webpage contains 4 images a total of 5 separate connections will be made to the web server to retrieve html and four image files.

How can i achieve such a scenario?

Here is my code:

```
PORT_NUMBER = 50000

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        os.chdir("/Users/hasnain/Desktop/server/document root directory")   #Sets the path to document root directory
        if self.path=="/":# Checks if the request is for root
            self.path="/index.html"# Sets to load index.html if the request is for root            
        try:
            #Check the file extension required and
            #set the right mime type

            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply = True

            if sendReply == True:
                #Open the static file requested and send it
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path) 
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.send_header('Content-length',mimetype)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read().encode())
                f.close()
                return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

try:
    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print ('Started httpserver on port: ' , PORT_NUMBER)

    #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('^C received, shutting down the web server')
    server.socket.close()
```